# how to detect partial corrupted images in Jpg/Jpeg format

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In a very big image dataset, we have some corrupted images as following images. These images can be viewed without any problem, but human eyes can see some corrupted areas in gray color. How can I detect these corrupted images？

Actually I have written a script in Matlab for detecting. It could filter most of the corrupted images, but some will be miss. The main idea of my script is find common binary string of corrupted images. While some corrupted images don't obtain this common binary string. So they will not be filtered.

My Matlab code:

```
FOLDER1 = './'; % query data
query_folder1 = FOLDER1;
query_pt1 = dir(strcat(query_folder1, '*.jpg'));
nFile1 = length(query_pt1); % file number

BROKEN_MARK = '00455114';
SIZE = 4; % single size
THRESH = 3;

for i = 1:nFile1
    img_dir = strcat(FOLDER1, query_pt1(i).name());
    fid = fopen(img_dir);
    im1_stats = dir(img_dir);
    file_length = im1_stats.bytes;
    pos = -4;
    epost = -200;
    count = 0;
    while abs(pos) <= ceil(file_length)
        fseek(fid, pos, 'eof');
        temp = fread(fid, 1, 'single');
        str = num2hex(single(temp));
        if(strcmp(str, BROKEN_MARK))
            %fprintf('%s\n', img_dir);
            if(count >= THRESH)
                copyfile(img_dir, 'candidates/');
                break;
            else
                count = count + 1; 
            end
        else
            count = 0;
            pos = pos - 1;
        end
    end
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Could any one give some idea for detecting all corrupted images? Or any Python, C++, Matlab or bash script code. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is neither a c++ nor a python question. I have doubts as to whether it's even an image storage question, which is what the image tag is for. Did you mean image-processing, which is for information extraction from images?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. I will change it. Thank you.

Comment: Is the corrupted part of the image contained precisely in the bounds of the 8x8 pixel blocks jpeg transforms with the direct cosine transform, or can it include components with borders not on those bounds?

Comment: @jaggedSpire Ihave not understood you very precisely, but all corrupted parts are lie on right bottom part of corrupted images.

Comment: Most JPEGs store information regarding 8x8 pixel blocks. Detecting a solid grey one of those blocks is very, very simple compared with detecting a solid grey area which doesn't precisely occupy one of those blocks. Such a sharp edge would require detection of what is effectively a step function with a grey bottom area, *if* the other part of the block was entirely white or black. Read up on the JPEG format.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Thanks for advice. Other part of the image will be other colors, Now I am implementing similar methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used already detected corrupted images for analyzing corrupted parts. Then use these results to detect possible corruption. Here is Matlab code:

```
clear; clc;
FOLDER1 = './';
query_folder1 = FOLDER1; % Some corrupted samples are here.
query_pt1 = dir(strcat(query_folder1, '*.jpg'));
nFile1 = length(query_pt1); % file number

OFF = 10;

for i = 1:nFile1
    img_dir = strcat(FOLDER1, query_pt1(i).name());
    img = imread(img_dir);
    [x y ~] = size(img);
    img_part = img(x-OFF:x, y-OFF:y, :); % Get samples from right-bottom corner
    hist(i, :) = rgbhist_fast(img_part, 4); % get RGB histogram of sample part of corrupted region
end

mean_hist = mean(hist); % Use average of RGB histogram of samples for standard of corruption 

FOLDER2 = '~/data/logo_data/930k_iautocrop/'; % Main big dataset
query_folder2 = FOLDER2;
query_pt2 = dir(strcat(query_folder2, '*.jpg'));
nFile2 = length(query_pt2); % file number

for i = 1:nFile2
    if(mod(i, 100) == 0)
        fprintf('%d\n', i);
    end
    img_dir = strcat(FOLDER2, query_pt2(i).name());
    img = imread(img_dir);
    [x y ~] = size(img);
    img_part = img(x-OFF:x, y-OFF:y, :);
    temp_hist = rgbhist_fast(img_part, 4);
    dist(i) = sqrt(sum((mean_hist - temp_hist').^2, 2)); % get corrupted similarity
    %imshow(img_part);
end

[v ix] = sort(dist, 'ascend'); % To find most corrupted images. The images on the top of the list have high corruption probability
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not technically corrupted if you can view them. They are "corrupted" in your perception. Personally I would count all gray pixels and if the  percentage is greater than a given amount the image is considered "corrupted", checked manually and deleted.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

persantage=10           # Corrupted area in per cent to detect
color=(128, 128, 128)   # Corruption color, tuple 

from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("corrupted.jpg")

pixels = list(im.getdata())
width, height = im.size
pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width] for i in xrange(height)]

gray=0
other=0
for data in pixels:
    for pix in data:
        if pix == color:
            gray += 1
        else:
            other += 1


corruption_area= gray *100 / (gray+other)


if corruption_area >= persantage:   
    print 'Corruption:', corruption_area, '%'
else:
    print 'OK'
```

Output for the attached image below is

```
Corruption: 18 %
```

[image]

Comment: Actually this code will work for some corrupted images but not all of them. Because some gray color is not 128. So I used machine learning for detecting them.  I will attach my code. Thank you.

Comment: Then change the color.

Comment: these color are similar but different, and dataset is very big. I can't change it each time. I have pasted my answer. I think it is more robust.

Comment: You can run the script in a loop for all RGB colors available. I guess, you are smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: It is a possible way, but it is not efficient enough. Thank you for discussion.

Comment: You are welcome. Can describe the  efficiency algorithm? I am not as advanced  as reading minds yet. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, the efficiency is  the time of processing single image. And I have 1 million images, so the efficiency is important factor.

Comment: You can shrink the original image. Percentage will stay the same. Or instead of counting all pixels you can define a sequence of the same pixels, say, if 10 pixels are the same in a row, the image is bad. It's up to you.

Comment: I know we can make your method work my problem, but I think mine is better than you.

Comment: That's what it is. I wondered what the hack the efficiency was. Thanks for clarification.